# onload not working when using jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, onload

I need to fire the script when elements are loaded via ajax and appended to the DOM.

here is HTML

```
<div id="one">
  <p>one</p>
  <button>Append</button>
</div>
```

and here is javascript

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  //in real life s is loaded via ajax
  var s="<p onload='myalert();'>two</p>";
  $('#one').append(s);
})

function myalert() {
  alert('ok');
}
```

The alert will never fire. How to catch the event when elements are fully loaded?

Here is codepen sandbox for playing around: https://codepen.io/xguntis/pen/rQERmW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to fix your issue.
So I found a way to fix your problem.
This is my code

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  //in real life s is loaded via ajax
  var s="<p>two</p>";
  $('#one').append(s).ready(function(){
    alert('ok');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="one">
  <p>one</p>
  <button>Append</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `onload` event there. Why not just have the `alert` statement at the end of your event handler?

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  //in real life s is loaded via ajax
  var s="<p>two</p>";
  $('#one').append(s);
  alert('ok');
})
```

Comment: Because the task is bit more complex. I need to read the width of the image loaded with append. And it is 0 because the image is not loaded yet after the append statement.

here is the updated script part: https://codepen.io/xguntis/pen/qQzwbQ

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  //in real life s is loaded via ajax
  var s="<p id='twoP' >two</p>";
  $('#one').append(s).ready(function(){
    alert('ok');
  });
})
```

this will load the element then will fire the call back